# setstate() with list.lengh parameter didn't work

Tags: json, reactjs, list, axios

I tried to count the number of items in my list "data"

my component looks like that :

```
BuildMap() {
  axios.post('http://104.xx.xx.xxx:8081/children', {action: "list"}, {headers: {'x-access-token': this.props.base.Token}})
     .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        this.setState({data, NbrProfil: data.length});
        })
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

"data" is correctly returned and here is what it's return :

```
[
{
    "name": "Mia",
    "age": 12,
    "options": [],
    "discordId": "12",
    "alerts": 0,
    "warnings": 0
},
{
    "name": "Demetra",
    "age": 12,
    "options": [],
    "discordId": "12",
    "alerts": 0,
    "warnings": 0
}
```

]

sadly "NbrProfil" stay undefined and could be "2" ...
can I have some help please ?

Comment: thanks sadly it's just a mistake when I wrote the post ... I just edit it

Comment: Why do you need to store array length separately in state if you have entire array there? Just use `this.state.data.length` wherever you need it.

Comment: The way you're assigning your list length to NbrProfil seems just fine. 
1 - Are you using definining this "BuildMap" function inside a React component? Your setState should only be available there.
2 - How are you calling your state to use this NbrProfil?

Comment: Just try coping the data and assign. `const data = [...res.data]`

Comment: thanks for all your help guys. I just try to use ```this.state.data.length``` like Yury said and it work. It's weird i'm pretty sure I already try this way ...